# Where are the latest Undertow server docs?

Tags: undertow

The [Undertow documentation page](https://undertow.io/documentation.html) seems pretty stale: the latest documentation is only for v2.1.0 (apparently from April 2020!), but [on Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:io.undertow) the latest version is v2.3.10.Final. The [GitHub page](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow) doesn't seem to have any more recent documentation. I saw that the links to an offline ZIP documentation archive mentions `undertow-docs-2.1.0.zip`, so I thought maybe that the latest docs would be published on Maven Central, but a [search there for `undertow-docs`](https://search.maven.org/search?q=undertow-docs) yields nothing.

Where can I find the latest documentation for Undertow, e.g. for v2.3.10.Final?